# evolution mapi not working in 13.04

Tags: 13.04, email, evolution, evolution-mapi

After installing evolution-mapi in Ubuntu 13.04, I am getting this error

```
(evolution:8018): camel-CRITICAL **: camel_provider_list: 
Could not load /usr/lib/evolution-data-server/camel-providers/libcamelmapi.so: 
libdbwrap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And Evolution Mapi does not show up in the list of providers when setting up emails. How do I resolve this?

my list of installed evolution packages are :

```
$ sudo dpkg-query -l | grep evolution
ii  evolution                                 3.6.4-0ubuntu1
ii  evolution-common                          3.6.4-0ubuntu1
ii  evolution-data-server                     3.6.4-0ubuntu1
ii  evolution-data-server-common              3.6.4-0ubuntu1
ii  evolution-indicator                       0.2.20-0ubuntu10
ii  evolution-mapi                            3.6.2-0ubuntu1
ii  evolution-plugins                         3.6.4-0ubuntu1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package `python-samba` installs the missing lib file.  However once I got past that issue, Evolution won't save my account info for my newly created Exchange account.  Curious if you experience the same thing.

EDIT: Had to kill all evolution related processes.  Then two attempts I made at setting up my exchange account showed up as two accounts in Evolution.  Removed one and everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Thanks. That enabled MAPI. However, I think our server is behind the proxy, which is not supported yet. So I am out of luck!

Comment: Worked perfectly after pulling my hair out for a while. This dependency needs to be fixed.

Comment: I also could not create an account.  Killed the processes and they showed up!  I also had to kill the processes a second time to get my account's folders to show up.  All is well since then.

Answer (score 0):

you need to at least log out and login again to see the new accounts, you will need to restart for the calendar to start working. at least thats what i had to do on 12.10.